# Filter not working on SoundCloud tracks search

Tags: soundcloud

According to the SoundCloud API documentation I should be able to specify filter=streamable on a search against tracks and (presumably) only get replies that are streamable. It's not working.

```
https://api.soundcloud.com/tracks.json?q=diddy&filter=streamable&client_id=<CLIENT_ID>
```

That returns some results that aren't streamable. Filtering the results myself is not desirable because I'm trying to fetch pages of a certain size.

Comment: i wouldn't rely on soundcloud api docs. they started a new apis with next soundcloud (which are not documented still), and from my experiene, they don't care so much for old code. this is obvious, since they still have lots of problems and work to do (still) on next soundcloud.

Comment: my suggestion would be, do the search and then filter the results yourself.

Comment: Thanks. I guess I'll have to build my own buffer of results so I can display the correct number of results per page.